# What does GL in 'Mapbox GL JS' stand for?

Tags: mapbox

I couldn't find it in the introductory docs

https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-web-apps-work/#mapbox-gl-js

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

GL is a reference to WebGL (Web Graphics Library). So it stands for 'Graphics Library'

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL

Mapbox uses Mapbox GL JS, a client side renderer, so it users JavaScript and WebGL to draw the data dynamically with speed and smoothness of a video game. 
A more detailed explanation can be found on this SO answer...

[Mapbox GL JS vs. Mapbox.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069753/mapbox-gl-js-vs-mapbox-js)

Esentially MapBox GL is a upgrade of Mapbox JS to exploit the client side WebGL technology (amongst other upgrades).